# Get the combined value of multiple select menus jQuery

Tags: jquery, var

Working on a project with a vehicle selector. The idea is that the user selects their make, model, and year from select menus, and when they click the add button, it adds the combined value of the three (in a specific order) to an adjacent unordered list.

I'm just now starting to learn how to collect the values of form controls. I think I'm on the right track, but I'm not quite there. When I click add, it adds a list item with the value of "object Object".

Here's my js:

```
$('.vehicle-select button').click(function (e){
var make = $( "#make option:selected" ).text();
var model = $( "#model option:selected" ).text();
var year = $( "#year option:selected" ).text();
var carName = $(year + make + model);     
$('.my-brands').prepend('<li>' + carName + '</li>');   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tactics/rcbc6908/

Ideally, I would like it if the user couldn't select the first option in each select, otherwise they could add a vehicle with a value of "Choose Year Choose Make Choose Model".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var carName =[year,make,model].join(' ');
```

Comment: All of these answers work, but this one works the best because it preserves a space in between the values and is the shortest. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are creating a new jquery object from the selected values when you include `$`. Use this:

```
 var carName = year + " " + make + " " + model;
```

instead of

```
 var carName = $(year + make + model);
```

If you want to use `$`, you could do this:

```
 var carName = $('<li>' + year + " " + make + " " + model + '</li>');
 $('.my-brands').prepend(carName);
```

Answer (score 0):

[see my updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/rcbc6908/2/)

You don't need to put a $( around your concatenation).

It should look like

`var carName = year + make + model;`

instead of

`var carName = $(year + make + model);`

The reason being is year make and model are represented as strings so the + operator will concatenate them as is. The concatenation due to the + operator is not a jQuery feature so you do not need to wrap it in $().